# Is there a better way of doing this C++, Saving and loading variables from files of any type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, boost

I've been using a class I have written (here is a cut down version that works) that provides a method for loading and saving any variables from strings, and can be added to the class provided the class has this object in it and it is called _settings_loader. Each variable is added via the #define ADD_PARAMETER(x) _settings_loader.AddParameter(#x, x); macro.

I would love it if someone can suggest an easier way of expanding this rather than using each individual case for each type? I know C++ is type defined but has what I'm trying to do been done before (I don't want to use templates when I add in each variable).

Header

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define ADD_PARAMETER(x) _settings_loader.AddParameter(#x, x);

class SettingsLoader
{
public:
  SettingsLoader();
  template <class T> void AddParameter(std::string name, T & parameter);
  void SetParameter(std::string name, std::string value);
  std::string GetParameterValue(std::string name);
  void PrintOutParameters();
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > GetAllParametersAsStrings();
protected:
  std::map<std::string, boost::any>  _parameters;
  bool _debug;
};


template <class T> void SettingsLoader::AddParameter(std::string name, T & parameter)
{
  _parameters.insert(std::make_pair(name, boost::any(&parameter)));

  if (_debug)
  {
    std::cout << "Added parameter " << name << std::endl;
  }
}
```

CPP

```
#include "settingsloader.h"
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

SettingsLoader::SettingsLoader():
  _parameters(),
  _debug(false)
{
}


void SettingsLoader::SetParameter(std::string name, std::string value)
{
  try
  {
    std::map<std::string, boost::any>::iterator itterator = _parameters.find(name);
    if (itterator != _parameters.end())
    {
      boost::any boost_any = itterator->second;

      if (boost::any_cast<double*>(boost_any))
      {
        double * value_to_set = boost::any_cast<double*>(boost_any);
        *value_to_set = boost::lexical_cast<double>(value);
      }
      else if (boost::any_cast<int*>(boost_any))
      {
        int * value_to_set = boost::any_cast<int*>(boost_any);
        *value_to_set = boost::lexical_cast<int>(value);
      }
      else if  (boost::any_cast<long*>(boost_any))
      {
        long * value_to_set = boost::any_cast<long*>(boost_any);
        *value_to_set = boost::lexical_cast<long>(value);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (_debug)
      {
        std::cout << "Parameter " << name << " could not be set" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
  catch(...)
  {

  }
}

std::string SettingsLoader::GetParameterValue(std::string name)
{
  try
  {
    std::map<std::string, boost::any>::iterator itterator = _parameters.find(name);
    if (itterator != _parameters.end())
    {
      boost::any boost_any = itterator->second;

      if (boost::any_cast<double*>(boost_any))
      {
        double * value_to_get = boost::any_cast<double*>(boost_any);
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*value_to_get);
      }

      if (boost::any_cast<int*>(boost_any))
      {
        int * value_to_get = boost::any_cast<int*>(boost_any);
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*value_to_get);
      }

      if (boost::any_cast<long*>(boost_any))
      {
        long * value_to_get = boost::any_cast<long*>(boost_any);
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*value_to_get);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(...)
  {

  }
  return "";
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > SettingsLoader::GetAllParametersAsStrings()
{
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> output_vector;
  for (auto pair : _parameters)
  {
    output_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(pair.first, GetParameterValue(pair.first)));
  }

  return output_vector;
}


void SettingsLoader::PrintOutParameters()
{
  std::cout << "+=======================+" << std::endl
            << "|Printing out parameters|" << std::endl
            << "+=======================+" << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> names_and_values = GetAllParametersAsStrings();
  for (std::pair<std::string, std::string> pair : names_and_values)
  {
    std::cout << pair.first << " = " << pair.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing you might want to look at is Qt's implementation of a "typeless" object, [QVariant](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/b12a8d47ba8a803cae88718249b8d3f7d4a85948:src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.cpp). Note that they, too had to write different code for each type case, just like you're doing. There isn't any better way I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope of the project you should consider instead of solving the problem with c++ language instruments to start using code generators. There are several very good projects out there that solve way more problems than the one you describing:

For example: Google protocol buffers, Apache thrifty and many others

Answer (score 0):

This is called serialization or data marshalling.  And it is quite common to add serialize and deserialize methods to your classes.  For example, Python has 'pickle' as a way to serialize data objects to a binary format - exactly what you are doing.

Some of the better serialization formats (IMHO):

- (Google) ProtocolBuffers - binary, does what you want, available for C++, has IDL
- JSON - widely used/implemented, and cross language
- BJSON - binary json format (see MongoDB, among others)
- MessagePack - another binary json format, probably better than BJSON
- UBJSON - this might be the best binary json format
- xupl - this also appears to be a great format
- XDR - a bit older than than the JSON formats, but very good
- Pickle - it is specific to Python, but other languages have pickle libraries

Ruby augments objects with a .to_s (toString) to enable printing.  Following that same pattern, adding methods to your classes .serialize and .deserialize methods to your classes would give you much of what you want.  And using JSON or an IDL would give you something closer to the polymorphic deserialize you seek.  Keep in mind that JSON announces the member names, and IDL's serve much the same purpose.